# R matrix column to fill with timestamp

Tags: r, matrix, time

I'm trying to fill one matrix column with a date-time called up from another column.

```
B <- matrix(0, nrow(A) - 1, 3)
B[, 1] <- "Anne"
times <- as.POSIXct(tname$DT[1:955], format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
B[, 2] <- times
```

When returning times, it lists them in the format `"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"`,

```
 [1] "2017-05-19 11:01:00 EDT" "2017-05-19 12:01:00 EDT" "2017-05-19 
12:31:00 EDT" "2017-05-19 13:01:00 EDT"
  [5] "2017-05-19 13:31:00 EDT" "2017-05-19 14:01:00 EDT" "2017-05-19 
14:31:00 EDT" "2017-05-19 15:01:00 EDT"
  [9] "2017-05-20 08:01:00 EDT" "2017-05-20 09:01:00 EDT" "2017-05-20 
10:01:00 EDT" "2017-05-20 11:01:00 EDT" ....
```

however, when I call up `B[, 2]` it gives me weird numbers:

```
 [1] "1495206060" "1495209660" "1495211460" "1495213260" "1495215060" 
"1495216860" "1495218660" "1495220460"
  [9] "1495281660" "1495285260" "1495288860" "1495292460" "1495296060" ....
```

How do I copy my dates and times into my matrix in the right format?

Comment: That's because the timestamps are converted to character in a matrix. A matrix unlike a data.frame, can only hold data of one type

Comment: It's better to store your data in a data frame given that you have columns with different data types.

Comment: And those "weird numbers" are the timestamps numerical representation as seconds since 1970-01-01. So you can use `as.POSIXct(1495206060, origin = "1970-01-01")` to get the timestamp

Comment: Thanks to all! Very helpful!